Seeing / outputting memory usage of scrapy spider as it's running
I'm wanting to better monitor the memory usage of a scrapy spider as it's running (context: I'm running it on Heroku and seeing how I can restructure the scrape to stay more within the bounds of the dyno I'm using).
I've turned on the MEMUSAGE_* settings. But for closer monitoring, I'm wondering...

Is there any way to have the spider output its current memory usage as it's running? I'm thinking of something I could use in a print statement in the middle of the spider's code

As the spider is running, how can I see how much memory it's using? I think I see it in the output of top -o cpu as python 3.12, but I'm not certain it's the spider, since its memory usage doesn't seem to be accumulating as quickly as the same spider running on Heroku



Thanks for the suggestion. @wRAR cracked it below, but it's useful to know about tracemalloc

Just copy the code that gets the memory usage from the MemoryUsage extension and call it in your code:
import resource

def get_virtual_size() -> int:
    size: int = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
    if sys.platform != "darwin":
        # on macOS ru_maxrss is in bytes, on Linux it is in KB
        size *= 1024
    return size


Bingo, this works! Just a small typo - don't need the self for the self.resource.RUSAGE_SELF. Thanks for pointing this out!!
